# ruby on rails - cloning an entry along with its associated models data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I really need some help concerning cloning/duplicating an entry along with its associated data.
I have a submission which has associated submitter's details, notes + other associated information found in several tables.

I tried using the code below:

```
  def duplicate1
    submission_to_dup = Submission.find(params[:id])
    new_submission = Submission.create(submission_to_dup.attributes)
    end

    def duplicate2
    new_submission = Submission.create(Submission.find(params[:id]).clone);
    end
```

But it seems that both methods do a shallow copy of its parent object, without an ID or any associations.

Is there any way of duplicating a record along with its associated data?

Thanks a lot in advance for your precious help :)

Comment: I think if you could better explain what it is your trying to do, i.e., why you need to create a copy that includes the ID, it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: I want to duplicate a record, along with its associated data and manually allocate its ID(primary id).

Comment: The above methods i posted do not seem to be doing the job as they are simply duplicating the data of the primary model only and ignoring the data of the associated models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicating an object in ActiveRecord will never clone :id, b/c it's a unique primary key. And since that primary key should be the foreign key in the associations of that object, you're going to lose those as well. The only way I can think of to create a duplicate record is to do something like:

```
def duplicate_record
  rec = Submission.find(params[:id])
  new = Submission.new(:attr => rec.attr)
  if new.save
    new.update_attributes(:nested_attr => {:attr => rec.nested_attr.attr})
  else
    something else
  end
end
```

But I can't think why you'd want to. I spend most of my time trying to keep duplicate records **out** of my databases.

Anyway, hope this helps.